How to use a dimmer switch for 12v led puck lights
My lights don't have any drivers and I'm running them off of a 12v battery for my power supply. There are various switches that are advertised as 12/24v that fit in a typical outlet box. However they do not dim within the specified range. The following picture is one that I have tried but it only dims from 12.4v to 11.8v Does anyone know why this is? Should I try the 0-10v variant of these dimmer switches?

Is it possible that I need to add something like this to my circuit?


Likely, the switch is made for a higher load, e.g., incandescent lamp. You might try a pulse-width modulated speed control, instead, such as this from Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/Motor-Controller-Control-Switch-Dimmer/dp/B08T5TJWYH. N.B. Some LED's cannot be dimmed, and some can.

You'll probably want a PWM driver/controller for your LEDs...

At a minimum, you need the LEDs to be dimmable, and for the switch to be LED-compatible—have you confirmed those?
